# Error al enviar correos C Sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Para servidores de 16 de RAM no tengo problemas, se envia correos con normalidad, pero con servidores de menor memoria ram, no puedo enviar correos.

Le he agregado como tiempo de espera el siguiente pero persiste el problema.

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostCorreo"];
            client.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PuertoCorreo"]);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 2147483647;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Timeout = 214748
```

Que debo hacer para solucionar este problema ?

El mensaje de error es el siguiente, finalmente figura como si se estaría enviando, pero nunca se envian los correos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recibes algun error o algo en dichos sistemas?

Comment: Hola @DAES. Como bien te han comentado podrías indicar qué mensaje de error obtienes. O también revisar el visor de eventos de Windows por si hubiera alguna otra información. Puedes editar la pregunta para mostranos el código completo de tu método de envío de mails? Gracias

Comment: Hola Sergio, te respondo en las respuestas puesto que en esta sección no me permite agregar imágenes.

Comment: Me suena  más a alguna configuración del servidor, en teoría, si en un servidor te funciona y en otro no utilizando el mismo código se podría deber a algún ajuste, además de que el solo enviar un mail no consume (casi nada) recursos del server, también habría que ver el rendimiento de ambos servidores, ¿has revisado que todas las configuraciones entre los servidores sean las mismas?

Comment: Que host y que puerto usas? No veo que informes del Usuario y Password, y tienes `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`

Comment: @DAES ese mensajes que muestras es la imagen no es estandar de .net, es un mensajes que la aplicaicon define para controlar los errores, deberias definir un try..catch en el bloque que envia el mail y registrar cual es el mensaje de error real que recibes. No creo que la menmoria sea el problema salvo que quieras enviar un attach muy grande con el mail, pero aun asi seria raro